# JAXB behavior marshaling class with multiple setters with the same name

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

It is defined a class DataTO like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class DataTO {
    private boolean data;

    public Boolean getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(boolean data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(Boolean data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Using Java 6 the marshaling worked correctly and the XML generated was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataTO>
    <data>true</data>
</dataTO>
```

With Java 7 we encountered an issue that the XML is not generated correctly. We can reproduce the issue only in some specific complex environments, cannot be isolated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dataTO/>
```

Why is the different behavior depending on the Java version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is my theory.

Without any access type defined, your JAXB provider default access type is something which needs a getter/setter with matching types with the field.

What support this is that adding a getter with the boolean return type fix the problem in your example.

If you use an @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD), then no matter the getters/setters it works, because it ignores them.

For the different behaviour between java version, i can't explain it. Maybe your JAXB provider changed something in their implementation ?

Comment: Also, your initial example work for me in both Java 7 and 8.

Comment: Yes it works in a standalone application. I could not isolate the initial problem. We encountered the issue when migrating a large J2EE application from WebSphere 8 / Java 6 to WebSphere 8.5 / Java 7.

Comment: It seems that Websphere use a custom implementation of JAXB. My guess is that your problem come from a change in their custom implementation. Can you try to change your JAXB implementation to the reference one by setting com.ibm.xml.xlxp.jaxb.opti.level=0 in websphere system properties ?

Comment: Adding the setting com.ibm.xml.xlxp.jaxb.opti.level=0 solved the issue we have. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

How I succeeded to isolate the behavior is changing a bit the DataTO class:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class TestMain {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class DataTO {
        private boolean data;

        public Boolean getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(boolean data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataTO.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        DataTO d = new DataTO();
        d.setData(true);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(d, sw);
        System.out.println(sw);

        DataTO dd = (DataTO) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(sw.toString()));
        System.out.println(dd.getData());

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you change the data type from boolean (primitive) to Boolean (Wrapper), (Don't forget to adapt the types in setters/getters too) and see what happens ?

Comment: If I change from boolean to Boolean it works. What I would like to know why it does not work with the initial combination?